# How to create JSON object with array of nested arrays for multipletimes and multiple times?

Tags: php

```
$data=array
(
    "Maths" : [ 
        {
            "Name"  : "ramesh",        // First element
            "Marks" : 67,
            "age"   : 23
        }, {
            "Name"  : "mayur",    // Second element
            "Marks" : 65,
            "age"   : 21
        }
    ], 
"Science" : [
        {
            "Name"  : "ram",     // First Element
            "Marks" : 56,
            "age"   : 27
        },
        {
            "Name"  : "Santosh",    // Second Element
            "Marks" : 78,
            "age"   : 41
        }
   ]
);
```

Comment: `json_encode` and `json_decode` ring a bell. Just create assoc arrays for the objects, and a regular, numerically indexed array, for the bits that are arrays

Comment: can any one help me ? how to print data as above formating ?

Comment: `echo json_encode($data);` if you change the array according to what I've said (assoc arrays for `{key: val}` pairs, and regular arrays for `[some, values]` bits). That's _it_. [Just *RTFM*](http://www.php.net/json_encode)!

Answer (score 2):

You can create `$data` and encode json like this

```
<?php
$data = array
(
    "Maths" => array(
        array(
            "Name" => "ramesh", // First element
            "Marks" => 67,
            "age" => 23
        ), array(
            "Name" => "mayur", // Second element
            "Marks" => 65,
            "age" => 21
        )
    ),
    "Science" => array(
        array(
            "Name" => "ram", // First Element
            "Marks" => 56,
            "age" => 27
        ),
        array(
            "Name" => "Santosh", // Second Element
            "Marks" => 78,
            "age" => 41
        )
    )
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: thanks for anw but it's my output actually i wan't coding for same output  ?